# Loop Function with Interaction Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, plotly

New in Python/Plotly, I'm trying to 'optimize' an interactive plot with plotly

below is df

```
Date    AA  AQ  AS  B6  CO  DH  DL  EV  F9  FL  HA  HP  MQ  NW  OH  OO  TZ  UA  US  WN  XE  YV  DayofMonth  Month
27/12   5.0 0.0 2.0 6.0 3.0 NaN 2.0 6.0 2.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 1.0 9.0 0.0 5.0 5.0 17.0    1.0 2.0 27  12
28/12   8.0 0.0 3.0 2.0 0.0 1.0 6.0 4.0 1.0 3.0 1.0 0.0 5.0 3.0 1.0 3.0 0.0 6.0 4.0 19.0    6.0 0.0 28  12
29/12   2.0 NaN 1.0 NaN 1.0 0.0 11.0    4.0 4.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 4.0 6.0 2.0 4.0 0.0 6.0 3.0 13.0    6.0 2.0 29  12




import plotly.graph_objects as go


# Initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()
df= pivot_gp.copy()

# Add Traces
for col in ['AA',   'AQ',   'AS',   'B6',   'CO',   'DH',   'DL',   'EV',   'F9',   'FL',   'HA',   'HP',   'MQ',   'NW',   'OH',   'OO',   'TZ',   'UA',   'US',   'WN',   'XE',   'YV']:
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= list(df.Date), y= list(df[col]), name= f"{col}", line= dict(color="red")))


fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(active= 0, 
                                    buttons=list([dict(label= "None",
                                                       method= "update",
                                                       args= [{"visible": [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                                                           False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]}, {"title": "Unique Carriers"}]),

                                                  dict(label= "AA",
                                                       method= "update", 
                                                       args= [{"visible": [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                                                           False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]}, {"title": "Unique Carrier: AA"}]),

                                                  dict(label= "AQ", 
                                                       method= "update", 
                                                       args= [{"visible": [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                                                           False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]}, {"title": "Unique Carrier: AQ"}]), 

                                                  dict(label= "All", 
                                                       method= "update", 
                                                       args= [{"visible": [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]}, 
                                                             {"title": "Unique Carriers"}]),

                                                  ]), ) ])
```

As you can see, I've been able to create a loop to iterate over columns and add a line in the interactive plot. However, I'm having an issue for the update function.

Question:

How can I create a loop to iterate over all columns and add True when it's the right column for eg:

```
for col in [cols]:
     fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(active= 0, 
                                            buttons=list([dict(label= f"{col}",
                                                               method= "update", 
                                                               args= [{"visible": [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                                                                   False,False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]}, {"title": "Unique Carrier: f'{col}'"}]),
```

The challenge is in the args list, while looping:

- col 1 must be True then all False
- col 2 False, True, then all False
- col 3 False, False, True, then all False
- and so on...

Bonus Question: Just to make it 'pretty', in the first loop how can I change color for each column in:

```
line= dict(color="red")
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help you:

1. Replace

   ```
   for col in ['AA',   'AQ',   'AS',   'B6',   'CO',   'DH',   'DL',   'EV',   'F9',   'FL',   'HA',   'HP',   'MQ',   'NW',   'OH',   'OO',   'TZ',   'UA',   'US',   'WN',   'XE',   'YV']:
   ```

   with

   ```
   for col in df.columns:
   ```
2. To change the visible list you can try:

   ```
   "visible":[ x==col for x in df.columns]
   ```
3. For the color, you can set a dictionary:

   ```
   color_dict = { 'AA':"red", 'AQ':"blue", 'AS:"green"} 
   line = dict(color = color_dict.get(col))
   ```